# How do I implement a many to many to many relationship between 3 variables while limiting the combinations of the 3 that actually exist?

Tags: relational-database, mysql-workbench

I'd like to implement a relational database that stores the holdings of different mutual funds at different dates. In other words, each observation is a unique combination of a mutual fund, a stock, and a date. Each combination of those 3 variables also has a corresponding data point for the number of shares of the stock the mutual fund owned on the given date. From what I understand, I cannot implement this with two simple many-to-many relationships between the stock, mutual fund, and date variables.

The reason for this is that while a combination of a mutual fund and date, and stock and date might exist, the unique combination of the mutual fund, stock, and date might not. For example, Apple (the stock) might exist on 12/31/2015, and Fidelity Contrafund (the mutual fund) might exist on 12/31/2015, but Fidelity Contrafund might not own Apple on 12/31/2015.

Comment: Cardinality is just one propery of a given relationship/association. One is completely characterized/represented in some situation/state by a table value. Read about various notions of & notations for cardinality (binary & non-binary) in some information modeling textbook(s). The wikipedia E-RM article is not awful. (It is actually possible to represent/encode n-ary relationships/associations by binary relationships involving pairs that satisfy other binary relationships; but there is no *point* in doing so.) Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design.

Comment: See [Binary Equivalents of Ternary Relationships in Entity-Relationship Modeling: a Logical Decomposition Approach](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.4274&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for an explanation of which kinds of ternary relations can be losslessly decomposed into binary ones.

Answer (score 1):

Any relationship with any number of roles can be represented as a table. You'll have columns to identify each of the domains, as well as any dependent variables. Then, create a composite primary or unique key from the components in many-roles.

For example, you could create the following table:

```
holdings (mutual_fund PK, stock PK, date PK, shares)
```

Some people prefer to introduce a surrogate/autonumber key as primary key. That's fine, as long as the combination of `(mutual_fund, stock, date)` is indicated as a unique key.

MySQL Workbench, and other data modeling programs like it, use pre-relational (and pre-entity/relationship model) concepts when they equate tables with entity sets and foreign key constraints with relationships. They're still good for designing table schemas, just ignore their terminology.